# Uncovering underbrace without shift

Tags: beamer

I am preparing a presentation with beamer and I have a formula with an `underbrace` that I want to uncover in the following slide. What I do is

```
\only<1>{
  \[
    formula
  \]
}

\onslide<2->{
  \[
    \underbrace{formula}_{text}
  \]
}
```

It works fine but there is a slight movement in the formula in the transition from the first to the second slide. It's not a vertical jump (I have already used an `overlayarea` for that), but an horizontal shift.

Do you know a way to get rid of this (small) problem? I had thought about using `phantom` but I don't know how.

## EDIT

Preparing a MWE was not easy! In fact, I could not reproduce the problem... In the end I managed to with this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\only<1-2>{
    \[
        \overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}}=\overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}}+\onslide<2->{\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}
    \]
}

\onslide<3->{
    \[
        \overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}} = \underbrace{\overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}}+\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}_{\text{too long!}}
    \]
}\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

You can see a slight shift in the transition from the 2nd to the 3rd slide. What caused the problem was the introduction of the second `overbrace` but (a) I don't know why and (b) I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please post an entire compilable example that generates the problem you're looking to fix, not just a code snippet.

Comment: Top alignment of the frame could be a workaround. `\begin{frame}[t]`

Comment: @Mico I have added a MWE

Comment: @samcarter unfortunately top alignment does not do what I want (the problem is horizontal and not vertical)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put an `\onslide` before the end of the `\underbrace`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\only<1-3>{
    \[
        \overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}} = 
        \underbrace{
            \overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}} + 
            \onslide<2->{\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}
        \onslide<3->}_{\text{too long!}}
        \onslide<2-> + m + n
    \]
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: `\onslide` can be used after the `\underbrace` to show later parts of the formula (+m+n above) earlier

Comment: It works in this case, but not if I have a long formula and want two underbraces to appear later. With your code, the second part of the formula would be hidden in the first slide.

Comment: @minomic: does this cover it?

Comment: this is one serious trick! hats off to you!

Answer (score 4):

Dirty dirty trick:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
\color<1>{normal text.bg}
\underbrace{\textcolor<1-2>{normal text.fg}{formula}}_{text}
\color{normal text.fg}
\]

bla

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

**Applied to your MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
    \color<1-2>{normal text.bg}
    \textcolor<1-3>{normal text.fg}{\overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}} =} 
    \underbrace{%
        \textcolor<1-3>{normal text.fg}{\overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}}}
        \textcolor<2-3>{normal text.fg}{+\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}
    }_{\text{too long!}}
\color{normal text.fg}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the dirty trick. :-) Could you post an addendum to show how to apply this trick to the MWE code the OP has posted in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, just adding a `\thinmuskip` space (or `\,`) at the end of slide three removes the jumping:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.3\textheight}
\only<1-2>{
  \[
    \overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}} = \overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}}+\onslide<2->{\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}
  \]
}

\onslide<3->{
  \[
    \overbrace{a+b}^{\text{qq}} = \underbrace{\overbrace{c+d+e}^{\text{abc}}+\overbrace{f+g+h+i+j+k+l}^{\text{def}}}_{\text{too long!}}
    \,
  \]
}\end{overlayarea}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting observation! Actually I tried in a more complex example and it seems it does not work. Moreover, some characters remain stable, while other move slightly. So I guess compensating is not always possible.

Comment: @minomic: I'm sure it depends on the number of components in your "more complex" examples.